# Managed Object Context

Tags: swift, core-data

This line of code:

```
if let context = delegate?.managedObjectContext {
```

gives the error:

> App Value of type'AppDelegate'has no member 'managedobjectcontext'.

I've checked Core Data when I start and tried every step that Stack Overflow says, but cannot fix it. Please help me. 
Should I start over?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing your code. Do you understand the meaning of the error message?

Comment: It's telling you that your `AppDelegate` class doesn't have anything named `managedObjectContext`. Have you verified that this exists?

Comment: `managedobjectcontext` != `managedObjectContext`